# Changing CRS for basemap from OpenLayers plugin

Tags: qgis-plugins, coordinate-system, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I'm working on plotting data from NYC (Queens, specifically) and I would like to overlay my heatmap on a basemap from the OpenLayers plugin to show the location of streets, parks, etc. Because I'm plotting city level data I want to use an appropriate CRS for NYC: NAD83 / New York Long Island (ftUS) EPSG:2263. However, the base map from OpenLayers comes WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator EPSG: 3857. Also, I have on the fly reprojection enabled.

When I try to change the OpenLayers layer to EPSG: 2263 it plots my data from Queens off of the West coast of Africa. I've tried adjusting the layer crs settings and it seems that I can only get my data to plot correctly on the basemap if my openlayers basemap layer is in EPSG: 3857.

Is it possible to project an OpenLayers layer to a CRS other than 3857 without this issue and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. The layers that this plugin uses(Google, Bing, osm) are tilted only in this projection. Therefore, they can only be consumed in this projection.

Unless you are doing something which requires very high precision, you should be fine with web-Mercator as your projection.