# CRS not lining up with base maps from OSM plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have QGIS 2.18.

I have a selection of routes that I have mapped. Shapefiles of these routes are in WGS84:4326

When I want to map them with a base map of google maps or OSM, it only works when the basemap and the project is in its default WGS84:3857(OTF) projection. But if I change it to 4326 (OTF), the map shifts. Depending upon zoom level, it shifts to different places.

At 3857 :
[image]

At 4326:

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Try the QuickMapServices plugin instead of Openlayers

Comment: @underdark I'm sure this must be a duplicate but can't find a match?

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122951/misplaced-google-maps-with-openlayers-plugin-in-qgis , https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85662/changing-crs-for-basemap-from-openlayers-plugin , https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95793/openlayers-plugin-in-qgis-error-in-projection-3857-pseudo-mercator

Comment: @IanTurton I was also looking for one, but most candidates refer to the print compser